# Points A & B have coordinates A (-2, 5) and B (3, 9). Find a unit vector parallel to the vector AB

Tags: vectors

[This is what I got but it was wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktFV5.png)

I have attempted this question and attached an image of my attempt, and I don't see where I went wrong or what I could've done.

Comment: The norm of your vector is not 1. Obtain $\mu$ such that $||v||=1$ and you're all done.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Your vector $AB=(5,4)$ is correct.

Now you must find the length of this vector and then divide by that length.